# My ActionScript program acts weird

Tags: actionscript-3

I recently started trying to program in ActionScript after not using it for several years, and I started with Pong, because that seemed like an easy game to implement, but my (very rudimentary) code to bounce the ball off the top and bottom walls for some reason gets stuck bouncing up and down on the top wall...

Can anyone help?

```
import flash.events.Event;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mov);

var ySpeed:int = -5;

function mov(e:Event) {
        trace(ySpeed + " " + ball.y);
        ball.y += ySpeed;
        if (ySpeed < 0 && ball.y <= 0) {
                ySpeed *= -1;
        }
        if (ySpeed > 0 && ball.y >= 360) {
                ySpeed *= -1;
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to reset the y position as well or it'll keep inversing the ySpeed. Basically also add `ball.y = 0;` and `ball.y = 360;`. If you want to be more advanced and less jittery, use `ball.y = 0 + ySpeed;` and `ball.y = 360 - ySpeed;`. `0 +` is obviously optional.

Answer (score 0):

You code appears to be continually switching the speed vector as the 'hit' event keeps being triggered.

There are a few methods around this like
 - put an active delay on the 'hit' method (your 'if' statements)
 - track the direction that the object was travelling BEFORE it hit, then use this as an additional comparison parameter within the if statements
 - on impact switch the speed vector PLUS 'bounce' the object slightly away form the impact edge

I would also suggest chaining the if statements so that the 2nd is fired after the first has changed values.

I've adjusted the code slightly to take account of the ball and stage's dimensions.

Something like:

```
import flash.events.Event;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mov);

var dirY:int = -1;
var ySpeed:int = -5;
var ballR:uint = ball.height/2;

function mov(e:Event) {
    trace(ySpeed + " " + ball.y);

    if (ySpeed < 0 && ball.y <= (0+ballR) && dirY == -1) {
        dirY = 1;
        ySpeed *= -1;
        ball.y = 0 + ballR;
    } else if (ySpeed > 0 && ball.y >= (stage.stageHeight-+ballR) && dirY == 1) {
        dirY = -1
        ySpeed *= -1;
        ball.y = stage.stageHeight - ballR;
    }

    ball.y += ySpeed;
}
```

Comment: @Emilie did the above a solve your question or do you need further help?